# How can I run a Jekyll powered website from HostGator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, jekyll

I want to create a website with 'dynamic' pages for a web app. I 'cant' use Node because HostGator charges more for a dedicated server (required for Node apparently). Looking for a solution such as Jekyll or RoR. Does anyone know how to spin up a simple webApp powered by these on an environment like HostGator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jekyll and RoR are not used for the same purpose. Maybe you can explain a little more what are the expected functionalities of your web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build your Jekyll site locally and upload the _site/ directory into your website folder on your shared HostGator folder. You could also use a git repo and push all the files from Jekyll's _site directory to master and then pull them down via ssh on your HostGator website folder. Or create a git hook or other automated way of updating the files.

Should be as easy as uploading a static html site, since that is what Jekyll is.

If you are looking to build a Rails site check out the HostGator guide here http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Do you know if this will work with say an Angular or Node built site? (sorry, new to this part of the business)

Comment: Angular.js shouldn't need really anything to run on the server since it is just javascript and html. You should be able to just upload it. Node on the other hand will require node to be installed on the server. I'm not sure if HostGator has it installed or not. If you are on a shared plan and Node isn't installed you might have to upgrade your account or look elsewhere for hosting.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. HG allows for Node if you upgrade to a dedicated server. I am essentially looking to do as much cutting edge stuff as I can without having to upgrade.

Sounds like if I stick to Angular.js and 'ignore' Node for the time being I should be good to go. Thanks.